# fatal error when extending DateTime class

Tags: php, class, datetime, runtime-error

The same piece of code fails on one of my dev machines but runs on the other dev machine and my live server without complaint so I suspect this is a PHP configuration problem but am at a loss as far as how to resolve it.

```
class PGHQDate extends DateTime {}

$lastSeen = new PGHQDate();
$lastSeen->setTimestamp($this->_LastSeen); // int(10) unix timestamp
```

produces only on this certain box

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PGHQDate::setTimestamp()
```

just for fun I went and did this in the PGHQDate class...

```
public function setTimestamp($unixtimestamp) {
    parent::setTimestamp($unixtimestamp);
}
```

refreshing the page now yields:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::setTimestamp()
```

which makes me think I'm in over my head, because I was pretty sure you can't have a PHP install without that!

I'm running PHP 5.2.17 and `phpinfo()` says that Date/Time support is enabled.

Don't know what else to say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm running PHP 5.2.17

That's your problem right there; [`setTimestamp` is  available in PHP 5.3.0+.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php)